# Specify a foreign key on a non-unique reference column by additional reference

Tags: sql, reference, key, unique, where-clause

Example:

```
                                      survivor table

        owner_id                   unique_id    isDead  
      |__________                 |__________|__________
      |              foreign key  |          |    
      |   1234      ------------> |   1234   |   true  <--- this row is referenced
      |__________                 |__________|__________
                                  |          |    
                                  |   1234   |   false <--- this row should be referenced
                                  |__________|__________
```

Currently the code is like that:

```
CONSTRAINT `key_2` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `survivor` (`unique_id`)
```

I would like to have it function like that:

```
CONSTRAINT `key_2` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `survivor` (`unique_id`) WHERE `isDead` = false
```

but thats obviously not possible like that.

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `unique_id` is not actually unique. You should create a key by two columns in your second table (I mean `unique_id` and `isDead`). - then it will be unique combination. But you still won't be able to refer that by foreign key properly.

If you need to refer that via foreign key, you should store only valid owners in your second table: for example, delete those, who are not valid. If you want to keep them, you have to update their `unique_id` according to some algorithm, that preserves unique values and in the same time allows to separate valid values from invalid. Besides this, you'll need to store old values of `unique_id` - for example, create a new column named `old_id` and that will be:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| unique_id | isDead | old_id |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|   1234    |  false |  1234  |
+-----------+--------+--------+
|     -1    |  true  |  1234  |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

as you see, one of possible (but not best) solutions is to set `unique_id` to negative value. In sample above you will refer to correct row via foreign key and still able to restore connection of owner since `old_id` is stored. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, so in general that could be not an optimal way.

Comment: Yeah I know that my unique_id is not unique, but thats intentional. you're solution is interesting and could be a way to solve my problem but I would like not to add additional columns especially when I have to modify more. I want a solution like how you say it in your 2nd sentence. Referencing to an additional static isDead=true for the constraint.

Comment: No, you can not. Foreign key always referring to no more than one row (could be zero since second table may has no corresponding rows).

Comment: And its entirely not possible to let it ONLY refer to the row where not only owner_id=unique_id, but also isDead=false ?

Comment: You can **not** match one column into two columns. You can define a foreign key that will have reference to two columns, but your primary table must also have **two** referencing columns index with exactly same structure.

Comment: so if i had a static everytime isDead=false to my first table i can reference each to each or what do i have to do then? so i have two referencing and two matching colums in one(?) expression? EDIT: seems i have found out myself(?): CONSTRAINT `key_2` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`, `isDead`) REFERENCES `survivor` (`unique_id`, `isDead`)

Comment: As I've said, you must have two columns in your primary table to map that into your `unique_id, isDead` key. If your `isDead` is always constant, why store it at all?